# Rails create a method accessible via both the model and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there anyway to create a function I can call both in the model and controller? I have a function that grabs an array of files and strips the extension off and want to validate against the list. However I also want access to this list in the controller so I can output a select box for the options. I currently have this, however the VALID_MODULES doesnt get populated all the time.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize :init
  VALID_MODULES =[];

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :desc, presence: true
  validates :api, presence: true, :inclusion => { :in => VALID_MODULES}
  validates :filters, presence: true
  validates :toe, presence: true

  def init
    Dir.foreach('lib/resources') do |item|
         next if item == '.' or item == '..' or item == 'resource.rb'
            #Wont be called very often so O(n) complexity is fine (small #elements)
            VALID_MODULES.push(item[0..-4]) unless VALID_MODULES.include?(item[0..-4])
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: A couple of things.  1) Are these modules that are specific to the Job class?  Are they specific to the job instance? or are they global to the application 2) You also don't want to be doing this functionality on initialize as this will get executed for each record you pull from the database and will be very costly.  The answers to these questions affect the proper solution.

Comment: Peter, the valid_modules is really going to be global to the application. Yeah I thought that, it was the only way I could get it to be able to use the values as validation and to be able to access it in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a constant (`VALID_MODULES`), try making it an attribute of your `job`.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :valid_modules
  after_initialize :init


  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :desc, presence: true
  validates :api, presence: true, :inclusion => { :in => VALID_MODULES}
  validates :filters, presence: true
  validates :toe, presence: true

  def init
    @valid_modules ||= []
    Dir.foreach('lib/resources') do |item|
         next if ['.', '..', 'resource.rb'].include?(item)
         #Wont be called very often so O(n) complexity is fine (small #elements)
         @valid_modules << item[0..-4] unless @valid_modules.include?(item[0..-4])
    end
  end

end
```

Now in your controller you can just call `valid_modules` on your `Job` object to return the array.
Example:

```
job = Job.new
job.valid_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# in config/initializers/api_modules.rb
module ApiModules
  def self.modules
    # the Dir[""] glob syntax here I believe exclude dot directories
    # but I still like the Array#include? syntax here for your exclusions list
    # you may need to massage the strings of your file list to be more appropriate to your case
    @modules ||= Dir["lib/*"].select{|f| !["resource.rb"].include?(f) } 
  end
end

#app/models/job.rb
validates :api, presence: true, :inclusion => { :in => ApiModules.modules}
```

Comment: This is how I would write it atleast.  ValidModules is a bit nondescript to the use case.  It seems from your code a job needs to have a valid api module to be saved, so why not call it ApiModule? :)